# Save and Continue option while editing forms in MediaWiki

Tags: forms, save, mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I have created a form using the *"Create Form"* option in MediaWiki with few text areas to fill in by the user. I wanted to enable the option of **save and continue** wherein a user can save the form after filling it partially, and then continue adding/editing the information.

I used the [Extension:Checkpoint](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Checkpoint) to fulfill the same. The extension provides the option when [creating/editing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrclO.png) a normal page in mediawiki, but not when

- [Adding new information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CK8kD.png) in a form or
- [editing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XisL.png) old form using *"Edit with Form"* option

Searched a lot on ways to be able to use the same, but failed. Also tried using the *standard input tag:* **save and continue**, but it just creates text, and no button.

Is there a way to get the functionality to work (did I miss something), or implement it in another way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Save and Continue* option as a matter of fact can be easily implemented without the use of the Extension:Checkpoint.

The [standart input](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Semantic_Forms/Defining_forms#.27standard_input.27_tag) tag is defined within mediawiki which provides the user to provide different input options at the end of a page or a form.
The following different tag values are allowed:

- "save" (for the "Save page" button)
- "preview" (for the "Show preview" button)
- "save and continue" (for the "Save and continue" button - this lets users
- save the page without leaving the form)
- "changes" (for the "Show changes" button)
- "summary" (for the "Summary" text field)
- "minor edit" (for the "This is a minor edit" checkbox)
- "watch" (for the "Watch this page" checkbox)
- "cancel" (for the "Cancel" link)
- "run query" (for the "Run query" button in query forms)

The save and continue option can be easily used as follows:

```
{{{standard input|save and continue}}}
```

at the end of the page where you want the option.

It works as follows:

the button is not activated (appears as normal text) unless you type or change something in the form or page. As soon as you make even a slight change, the button is activated, to function just as every other button.

hence it might look as if the tag didn't work when it actually does. :)

PS: I still can't understand why the extension doesn't work on forms when it was designed keeping in mind the option of 'editing forms'.